# JQuery removed elements are still displayed

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom

I'm developing a website that emulates some "postit" functionality. When the user double clicks on the browser window, a form pops up (is made visible) that allows to introduce a message in an input text. By clicking on the form button, a postit element (`div.postit`) is created and displayed on the body (at the position where the user originally clicked). The `div.postit` includes a `div.msg` with the message and another `div.close` with an "x" that allows to close/erase the postit by clicking on the "x" (the `div.postit` -parent div- gets removed from body).

So far so good. But when the user double clicks again on the window and creates a new postit by clicking the form button, not only the new `div.postit` is displayed, but also the former postit (which was removed from the body) is displayed. Why is that?

This is a simplified version of my code. There is just one html form that is initially hidden by CSS and made visible on double click on the window:

```
// Event handler dblclick on browser window: Form is made visible
function ondblclickHtml(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  // Show form (fade in)
  $('form').fadeIn(1000);
  $('form').removeClass('hidden');

  // Pass (x, y) arguments to event handler wrapped inside an object
  $('input#nueva-nota').on('click', {x: x, y: y}, onclickButton);
} 


// Event handler for onclick form button
function onclickButton(event) {

  $('form').fadeOut(1000); // Form fades out

  var msg = $('input#note').val();
  var pos = [event.data.x, event.data.y]; // Retrieve the coordinates
  displayPostIt(msg, pos);
} 

function displayPostIt(msg, pos) {
  var $divPostIt = $('<div class="postit"></div>');
  var $closeDiv = $('<div class="close">x</div>');
  // Bind click event on close div
  $closeDiv.on('click', onclickCloseDiv);
  var $msgDiv = $('<div class="msg">' + msg + '</div>');
  $divPostIt.css({'left': pos[0], 'top': pos[1]});
  $divPostIt.append($closeDiv);
  $divPostIt.append($msgDiv);
  $('body').append($divPostIt); // Finally, append the PosIt div to the body
}

function onclickCloseDiv(event) {
  console.log("onclickCloseDiv ...");
  var divPostIt = $(this).parent();
  divPostIt.remove();
}
```

Comment: Each time you doubleclick the form, you're binding a new click handler to `input#nueva-nota`. It mean that from the second time you open the form, the input will have multiple event handlers binded and will call `onclickButton` multiple times. Also, I don't see any code that actually remove postit, only codes that create it. Is the removal process handled by a library?

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I removed by accident the remove at the last line, I've edited the code to include it.

Comment: What about the multiple handlers part?

Comment: Why not just jQuery('.postit').remove(); ?

Comment: @AVAT Yes, I understood that is my problem. I should take the bind for the onclick button out of the doubleclick event handler, then?

Comment: @Pat Dobson if I had several div.postit that would remove all of them, not just the one that was intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Avavt has already commented, your problem is that you are binding a new click event handler (along with the position info) to button, every time the user double clicks on window / body. So even if you remove the first post it and then double click on body second time, your first click handler is also going to get executed (and it will have the old position info) along with the new event handler that has the new position info. Thats the reason you get 2 `div.postit`s added. If you double click on body third time, there will be 3 `div.postit`s that will get added and so on.

The solution is to remove the dependency on `pos` to be passed as click event data. That way you can bind click event handler only once.

Here is a sample. I'm storing the `pos` data in a hidden field (`input#pos`) and then from `displayPostIt()` reading it back.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/738eh660/1/)

```
$(function(){
  $('input#nueva-nota').on('click', onclickButton);
  $(document).on('dblclick', ondblclickHtml);
})

// Event handler dblclick on browser window: Form is made visible
function ondblclickHtml(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  // Show form (fade in)
  $('form').fadeIn(1000);
  $('form').removeClass('hidden');
  $('input#note').focus();

  $('input#pos').val(JSON.stringify({'left': x, 'top': y}));
} 


// Event handler for onclick form button
function onclickButton(event) {

  $('form').fadeOut(1000); // Form fades out

  var msg = $('input#note').val();
  displayPostIt(msg);
} 

function displayPostIt(msg) {
  var $divPostIt = $('<div class="postit"></div>');
  var $closeDiv = $('<div class="close">x</div>');
  // Bind click event on close div
  $closeDiv.on('click', onclickCloseDiv);
  var $msgDiv = $('<div class="msg">' + msg + '</div>');
  var pos = JSON.parse($('input#pos').val());
  $divPostIt.css(pos);
  $divPostIt.append($closeDiv);
  $divPostIt.append($msgDiv);
  $('body').append($divPostIt); // Finally, append the PosIt div to the body
}

function onclickCloseDiv(event) {
  console.log("onclickCloseDiv ...");
  var divPostIt = $(this).parent();
  divPostIt.remove();
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way to solve how to pass the coordinates.